# Using a variable in JToken query

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

From the docs https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm

```
IEnumerable<JToken> price = o.SelectTokens("$..Products[?(@.Name == "AAA")].Price");
```

How could I re-write the above query where I have to find prices to match multiple product names from a list `["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using *SelectToken with LINQ* in the same link you provided.

To achieve your goal, you can write something like:

```
var names = new string[]{"AAA", "BBB", "CCC"};
var prices = o.SelectTokens("$..Products[*]")
       .Where(p => names.Contains((string)p["Name"]))
       .Select(p => (decimal)p["Price"])
       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the logical OR operator `||` in your [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query:

```
var query = "$..Products[?(@.Name == 'AAA' || @.Name == 'BBB' || @.Name == 'CCC')].Price";
var prices = o.SelectTokens(query);
```

If you need to build the query from some runtime array of names, you may do so e.g. using LINQ as follows:

```
var names = new []{ "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" }; // Or whatever

var query = names.Select((n, i) => (n, i))
    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder("$..Products[?("), 
               (sb, p) => sb.Append(p.i == 0 ? "" : "||").Append("@.Name=='").Append(p.n).Append("'"))
    .Append(")].Price")
    .ToString();

var prices = o.SelectTokens(query);
```

Note that [`JToken.SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) is intended to return a **single token** and will throw an exception if multiple tokens are matched.  If you expect multiple tokens to be returned use [`JToken.SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CG1Rd2).